# Proportional editing is not working

Tags: modeling, uv, rigging, texture-painting, uv-image-editor

Yes I know there's many questions on this answered already but nothing has worked for me. Proportional editing both on object and edit mode is not working for me. I am using my laptop keyboard and my wacom tablet.

When in object mode, I enable proportionAl editing set to smooth, pivot point on median,scale my object on the z axis ,sphere appears, then when I scaLe while pressing Pgdn and PgUp both on arrow buttons and numpad buttons, the sphere does not decrease or increase only the object does.[image]

And then when I try using it on edit mode, repeating the same steps as above, the vertices only move and nit the actual sphere itself [image]

When I press the numpad PgUp and Pgdn it moves the vertices like 5 times more like so[image]

This is how my keyboard looks like
[image]

Comment: Can you be more specific about what isn't working? When you try to proportional-edit, do you see any effect at all? Is it just the individual vertex which moves? Or are you seeing other unexpected behavior?

Comment: Hello :). Please add some [screenshots](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/) to better illustrate the issue.

Comment: Have you made sure the proportional editing radius is large enough and the mode set to connected?

Comment: Does it work in a new file?

Comment: I am using the blender docs and I am literally following what they say step by step.on edit mode, I put the pivot point on median point. I select a vertice,the sphere of influence appears then when I press PgUp and PgDn both on the numpad and arrow keys, the vertices are what move not the circle.

Comment: @Reese I have updated the question please have a look at it

Comment: @Vuyi Your description of the problem suggests there's a miscommunication somewhere. You described "scal[ing] while pressing PgDn and PgUp both on arrow buttons and numpad buttons". PgDn and PgUp are not keys on the arrow pad or the numpad; on my keyboard, they are keys labeled "pgdn" and "pgup" respectively just *above* my numpad. And by "scaling", do you mean pressing S (which shouldn't be used for this) or do you just mean "trying to adjust the size by pressing PgDn and PgUp"?

Comment: @JachymMichal I have updated the question. Please may you have a look at it

Comment: @JachymMichal thank you very much it's working now

Answer (score 2):

The <kbd>PgDn</kbd> and <kbd>PgUp</kbd> are secondary functions on your laptop keyboard.
Related: [On laptop when I press F3, no search bar shows up, just the brightness goes up?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/176622/78972)

You need to hold the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key to make them work.
Or you can use the pop-up menu slider.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The screenshots indicate that you have the select tool activated. For proportional editing to work, you must have one of the Move, Rotate, Scale, or Transform tools activated (they are the second to fifth tools down from the top).

First, enter *Edit Mode* and turn on proportional editing either by selecting the icon on the top of the screen or pressing the  <kbd>O</kbd> shortcut.

Select the vertices you want using the select tool (the one on the top left side with the arrow; use left click or <kbd>Alt</kbd> +  <kbd>A</kbd> to clear all), then hit the desired Move, Rotate, Scale, or Transform tool.

When this is done, the Gizmo tool appears, with its red, blue, and green arrows or circles, and the white circle of influence. Place the cursor in the Gizmo tool, and hold down the left mouse while simultaneously rotating the mouse wheel to change the size of the circle of influence (with me, this requires the use of the other hand).

Then use the cursor to grab the appropriate colored arrow or circle and move it. It takes a little practice.

The following YouTube videos are helpful:

1. Blender Proportional Editing Tutorial, by mrjhutton1.
2. YouTube, [2.93] Smooth Editing | How to use Proportional Editing | Blender 2.9x | Eevee & Cycles, by 5 Minutes Blender.
3. How to enable the Gizmo for translate, rotate, scale - shortcuts option | Blender 2.82 | Tutorial, by 25games.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing works for me, BUT... when I created a plane next to my object and tried the proportional editing method specified on the blender help page everything worked like magic. After it worked on the newly created plan, I tried to see if it also works on my object and it works!
I hope it will be useful.