# On laptop when I press F3, no search bar shows up, just the brightness goes up?

Tags: interface, shortcut

On my laptop I can't open any search bar because whenever I press <kbd>F3</kbd> the brightness just goes up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While i can't be sure, i would think, that the problem may be related to the  function key (<kbd>Fn</kbd>) for your laptop. Many keyboards come with multimedia keys that allow such functions, so i would not be to surprised if your laptop had an extra symbol on the <kbd>F3</kbd> key that was triggered instead.

Since i do not own such laptop, i show a part of an article i link below:
[image]

[Review Toshiba Satellite C855-2J4 Notebook
Jonas Adams, ✓ Stefanie Voigt (translated by Bernie Pechlaner)](https://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Toshiba-Satellite-C855-2J4-Notebook.102456.0.html)

As it shows, there are laptops that require you to press the function key (<kbd>Fn</kbd>) to access the <kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>F12</kbd> keys. While without you always press the multimedia/functional keys, to control brightness and volume and so on.

Not exactly Blender related, but i hope you can continue with your Blending.